# Does Google have an || (or)? Particularly for searching particular sites?

Tags: google-search, search

Say I wanted to search `site:wordpress.com site:livejournal.com gelato`. Doesn't work, because it tries to && those results instead of ||ing them. Say I want to do this for a number of sites such that it makes sense not to not restrict but also large enough so that it would be tedious to do this for every site (perhaps four or more specific site searches). **How do I get the || of results for `site:livejournal.com gelato` and `site:wordpress.com gelato`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `|` or `OR`.

So your example could be done like this: `site:wordpress.com OR site:livejournal.com gelato`.